# Can't update app betas to my beta-testers anymore (Ad-Hoc)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, provisioning

I've got an app that my client reviews continuesly via an distrubited ad-hoc* (mailed x.ipa + x.mobileprovision file) on every major development step. **This has work just fine until the mobileprovisioning profile was outdated** in august.

But it was not possible to just "renew" it i Xcodes Organiser window. Read some related posts but not found any answers to this yet.

**Known changes to my Dev. envoirement:**

The only changes I know happend since my client got his last working ad-hoc beta (created in the exakt same way*) is;

- Update to Mountain Lion on dev machine
- Update to Xcode 4.4.1 from 4.3.x
- Renewed my developer, provision and distribution outdated licenses in the Dev portal.

**Done this:**

- In the betatesting profile (mobileprovision) I've made sure I included the client's iPhone UDID.
- And I also doublechecked it via sedning an UDID-sending app in from the Store to the client.
- Also created another small app, w the normal ad-hoc steps*, but it didn't install on the betatesters iPhones either.

The app "works" this far: it can be transfered via mail to betatesters iTunes > Syncing to testers iPhone > and seems to install on iPhone, but just as it finished installing (progressbar on app icon goes away), then the beta app gets taken away. Can't even be found via search on the phone.

= This tells me it's not the app itselfs that is wrong but rather something with my provisioning certs from Apple or the dev portal or my Xcode. But which or what is it?!

- Taking away old outdated profiles in the Organizer.
- Updated profiles in Organizer w the Refresh-button**.
- Created new Betatesting distributionprofiles (x.mobileprovision) and used to in distribution of Archieves (ipa).
- Of course restared Xcode and my dev mac a couple of times.

**(Build app > Archive > Distribute > Betatest provisioning profile (x.mobileprovision) + x.ipa mailed to client)*

****Also related;**

When hitting the Refresh button in Organizer, all my profiles are valid (green) but I get this strange message;
"Your team ha no devices for which to generate a provisioning profile. Please connect a device to use for development or manually add a Device ID using the Provisioning Portal" Https...."
As far as I can see, I've got my dev iPhone connected and "green" under Devices on the left side of the Organizer. It's also included in my profiles.

FYI:

- All my profiles in the Xcode Organizer & Dev Portal, are "green" (ok).
- Run my Dev mac on OSX ML10.8.1, Xcode 4.4.1.

**Could anyone help out please?**

Been at this for days now, tryied many things, but just can't get it to work. Client's getting frustrated to! Also seem like I'm not alone on this - others also seem to have this problem. Thank's :-)

P.s. Maybe should mention that the beta app works fine on my dev iPhone...

*This topic is also on Apple Dev Forum: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/164981?tstart=0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
Will come back this weekend when I got more time and explain how and what was wrong in my Xcode and setup. Might be useful if someone else gets into the same frustrating trouble...

**UPDATE w solution:**

**The solution to my problem described above was;**

After a LOT of trail and error on this last week, I finally solved this.

**1) Make sure you have the correct UDID in Xcode > Organizer > Devices.**

- Fetch your testers latest UDID . I used the free app "UDID Finder" that did just that nicely (http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/udid-finder/id384382012?mt=8).
- Add / update the UDID's manually to the iOS Provisioning Portal online.
- Then refresh your local Xcode > Organizer > Devices.

**2) Make sure your provisioning & distribution profiles are up to date in the iOS Prov. portal.**

- Then refresh Xcode > Organizer > Devices > Library > Provisioning Profiles.

**3) Check your Xcode > Build settings**

- In your App > Choose top/root row (the hole project) > TARGETS > Your App > Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity;
- Make sure "Debug" has "[b]iPhone Developer[/b] + you provisioning profile" chosen and
- for "Release" has "[b]iPhone Distribution[/b] + your distribution profile" choosen. Also see example screendump attached.

[image: screendump]
<sub>(source: [meetup.com](https://files.meetup.com/4429322/Xcode4.4.1_CodeSigning.png))</sub>

A great link on the above (Apple Dev Forum); https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

My ad-hoc distribution to betatesters now works just fine. Hope this helps others :-)

**Conclusion:**
I believe the cause of the problem was that Xcode 4.4.1 (and maybe also the Xcode 4.5DP?) by default have set the building settings to some "wrong" defaults for me, which prevented me from distributing ad-hocs to my betatesters via mail.